# Possible typographical mistake in the definition of the normal curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

On the book [Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Manfredo P. do Carmo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486806995) the following definition can be found:

[image]

My question is very concrete: is there a typographical mistake in the formula boxed in red?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is absolutely correct. You're looking at the portion of the curvature vector $k\mathbf n$ that is *normal* to the surface (i.e., in the direction of $\mathbf N$). That is, you take $(k\mathbf n)\cdot \mathbf N = k(\mathbf n\cdot \mathbf N) = k\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

This complicated setup starts with a surface $S$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and a point $P$ with a normal unit vector to the surface $\vec N_S.$

[image]

Each point on the surface has an associated orthogonal vector (shortened in the diagram above to let the vector at $P$ stand out). The surface $S$ has domain boundaries between $-1<x<1$ and $-1<y<1$ and is governed by the equation:

$$f(x,y)=-x^2+\cos(x)+\cos(y)$$

The [normal vector to the surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) at any given point $\vec N_S(P)$ was calculated as:

$$\begin{align}
\vec N(t)&=\left (-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} ,-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t},1\right)\\[3ex]
&=\left(2x+\sin(x),\sin(y),1\right)
\end{align}$$

On $S$ a space curve $C\in \mathbb R^3$ was parameterized by $t$ with $-1<t<1$ as:

$$C(t)=(t,t^2,f(x,y))$$

On this space curve a tangent vector can be defined at each point as the curve derivative:

$$\vec T(t)=(1,2t,-2t-\sin(t)-2t\sin(t^2))$$

In the Frenet Serret or TNB frame $\vec T$ would be of unit $1,$ and defined as $\vec T=\frac{\vec r'(t)}{\vert \vec r'(t)\vert}=\vec r'(s),$ the latter part indicating that there is no need to normalize if the curve is parameterized by arc length $(s).$

A second orthogonal vector called the normal vector to the curve $C$ at $P$ can be calculated as the derivative to the tangent vector, provided that is parameterized by arc length as

$$\vec n(s)=\frac{\vec T'(s)}{\vert T'(s)\vert}$$

with $k(s)=\vert T'(s)\vert=\frac{\vert T'(t)\vert}{\vert r'(t)\vert}$ corresponding to the **curvature of $C$ at $P.$** However, this is not straightforward to compute given the square roots to normalize the derivatives, and as reflected [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3511972/276181). A way to circumvent this problem is to generate a vector via the wedge products

$$\vec n= \left( C'(t)\times C''(t)\right)\times C'(t)$$

and then proceeding to normalize it.

This vector can be used to generate the [osculating circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingCircle.html), knowing that the curvature can also be calculated as $k(t)=\frac{C'(t)\wedge C''(t)}{\vert C'(t)\vert^3},$ and that the radius of the osculating circle is $r=1/k:$

[image]

In the animation $\vec B(t)$ completes the [Frenet-Serret triad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas). $\vec B(t)$ is the binormal unit vector, the cross product of $\vec T$ and $\vec n.$ It is worth noting that since the derivative of the tangent vector $C'(t)$ is normalized its derivative $C''(t)$ is [orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3499297/152225). Together, $\{\vec T, \vec n, \vec B\}$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^3.$

The derivatives of $\vec T$ and $\vec B$ are in the span of $\vec n:$ The derivative of the tangent vector can be expressed as $T'(s)=k(s) \vec n.$ As a scalar product, $k(s) =\langle \vec n(s), T'(s) \rangle.$  Similary, the derivative of the binormal vector $\vec B$ can be expressed as $B'(s)=\tau (s) \vec n,$ where $\tau (s)$ is the **torsion of the curve $C$ at $s,$** which can also be expressed as a scalar product as $\tau (s) =\langle \vec n(s), B'(s) \rangle.$ That it makes sense for $\tau$ to denote the torsion of the curve can be seen by noticing how it stays constant if the curve is planar:

[image]

Here is an animation to illustrate the Frenet triad moving along the curve in relation to vector field $\vec N:$

[image]

The normal vector to the curve is in the span of the normal vector to the surface at any points along a geodesic curve:

[image]

Delving in the topic of the OP, $k_n=k\cos\theta$ is a scalar value with $\theta$ corresponding to the angle between $\vec N_S(t)$ and $\vec n(t):$

[image]

Since both $\vec N$ and $\vec n$ are unitary, the $\cos(\theta)=\langle \vec N, \vec n\rangle$ is given by the scalar product of the vectors.

The unit vector $\vec n$ multiplied by the scalar value of the curvature $k$ yields a vector $k\vec n,$ whose projection on $\vec N$ is $k_n\vec N:$

[image]

$K_n=k\cos\theta$ is called the **normal curvature** of $C$ at $P.$

The [geodesic curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature), $k_g,$ is the curvature of the curve projected onto the surface tangent plane. The geodesic curvature measures how far the curve is from being a geodesic:

[image]

---

And the punch line of the story is that if a vector $\vec v \in T_P S$ has norm $\vert v \vert=1,$ the second fundamental form applied to the vector, i.e. $\vec v^\top \mathbf{{II}_P} \vec v$ equals the normal curvature of *any* curve through $P$ at velocity $\vec v.$

The second fundamental form [corresponds to the Hessian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24130/152225) of a surface with a chart $f\left(u,v, h(u,v)\right),$ while [the trace of the Hessian is the Laplacian](https://qr.ae/pNrhFv). This makes intuitive sense, since the normal vector at a point $\vec N$ of a graph of a function is the gradient (vector of first derivatives), $\nabla F(x,t,f(x,y))=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, -1\right)(*),$ and the second fundamental form involved the derivative of the normal, $dN.$ The [second fundamental form can be expressed as a symmetrical matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034825/152225), which when applied to the derivative of a curve $\alpha(0)$ coursing through $p\in S$ at $t=0$ will result in (see [here](https://youtu.be/N569p-maOvM?t=1656)):

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{II}_p(\alpha'(0),\alpha'(0))&=-\langle dN_p(\alpha'(0),\alpha'(0)  \rangle\\
&=-\langle N'(0),\alpha'(0)  \rangle\\
&\underset{*}{=}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{\langle N(p),\alpha''(0)  \rangle}\\
&=\langle N(p),k(p) \vec n(p)  \rangle\\
&=k\langle \vec N_p,\vec n(p)\rangle\\
&=k_n(p)
&=k\cos\theta
\end{align}
$$

The boxed result being **Euler's theorem**: the acceleration of curve $\alpha$ at point $p$ dotted with the normal to the surface at the same point is the second fundamental form.

$(*)$ in an arc length parameterized curve:
$$\begin{align}
&\langle N(s),\alpha'(s)  \rangle =0\\
&\implies \langle N'(s),\alpha'(s)  \rangle+\langle N(s),\alpha''(s)  \rangle=0\\
\end{align}$$

The associated vectors to the minimum $k_1(p)$ and maximum $k_2(p)$ eigenvalues of the $\mathrm{II}_p$ restricted to vectors of norm $1$ in $T_pS$ will form an orthonormal basis of $T_pS,$ because $\mathrm{II}$ is a [symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/152225). $\{k_1,k_2\}$ are the **principal curvatures** of the surface at $p.$

A unit vector $\vec v\in T_pS$ in the tangent space can be thus represented in relation to the angle with these orthonormal basis vectors with $\vec v:$

$$\vec v=\cos \varphi \vec e_1 + \sin \varphi e_2$$

and applying the quadratic of the second fundamental form to $\vec v:$

$$\begin{align}
k_n=\mathrm{II}_p(\vec v)&=-\langle dN_p(\vec v), \vec v \rangle\\
&=-\langle dN_p(\cos \varphi \vec e_1 + \sin \varphi e_2), \cos \varphi \vec e_1 + \sin \varphi e_2 \rangle\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{-\cos^2 \varphi k_1 - \sin^2 \varphi k_2}
\end{align}$$

which is [**Euler's curvature formula**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerCurvatureFormula.html).

---

The surface $z=f(x,y)$ is identical to $F(x,y,z)=0,$ where $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z.$ Hence $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} F, \frac{\partial}{\partial z} F \right)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y),  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y),-1 \right).$