# Calculating the normal vector to a space curve to construct a 3D plot

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

In trying to follow the calculation of the normal curvature of a curve $C$ at a point $P,$ using Geogebra and a somewhat random example, I got stuck. Here is what I did:

The surface $S$ was set up as with domain boundaries for $-1<x<1$ and $-1<y<1$ as:

$$f(x,y)=-x^2+\cos(x)+\cos(y)$$

The space curve $C\in \mathbb R^3$ was parametrized by $t$ with $-1<t<1$ as:

$$C(t)=(t,t^2,f(x,y))$$

With $x=t$ and $y=t^2.$

The [normal vector to the surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) $\vec N$ was calculated as:

$$\vec N(t)=\left (-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} ,-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t},1\right)=\left(2t+\sin(t),\sin(t^2),1\right)$$

The tangent vector at point $P$ ($\vec T\in T_PS)$ was calculated as

$$\vec T(t) =\frac{d}{d t}C(t) =\left(1,2t,-2t-\sin(t)-2t\sin(t^2)\right)$$

This seemed to result in a plausible plot:

[image]

However, the calculation of the [normal vector to $C$ at $P$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) was not so happy:

$$\vec n=\frac{\vec T'}{\vert T\vert}=\frac{(0,2,-2\sin(t^2)-4t^2\cos(t^2)-2-\cos(t))}{\vert T\vert}$$

which would yield something like this (black arrow):

[image]

clearly not orthogonal to $\vec T.$

> Where did I go wrong in this calculation of the normal vector of $C$ at $P$?

I would like to calculate this normal vector to the curve by differentiation; however, the only way I have been able to produce some plausible plot is by first calculating the [binormal vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinormalVector.html):

$$\vec B=\frac{T\wedge T'}{|T\wedge T'|}$$

to later do the cross product of $\vec T$ with $\vec B:$

[image]

Comment: You've used $y=t$ instead of $y=t^2$ in a couple of places (eg first equations for $\vec N$ and $\vec T$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, with really nice pictures and explanations of what you've done so far.

First step: Heed @David's advice about $t$ and $t^2$. :)

But there is still another problem:

The normal is defined to be the derivative of the UNIT tangent. The thing you've called "$T$" isn't the unit tangent vector, and should really be given some temporary name, say, $U$, and then you define 
$$
T(t) = \frac{1}{\|U(t)\|} U(t)
$$
which is always a unit vector, i.e., you have
$$
T(t) \cdot T(t) = 1
$$
Take the derivative with the product rule, and you get

$$
T'(t) \cdot T(t) + T(t) \cdot T'(t) = 0
$$
so that 
$$
T'(t) \cdot T(t)  = 0
$$
as expected. But if you compute $U'(t)$, it's likely, in all but exceptional cases, to have a large component in the $T(t)$ direction.

**Post-comment addition**
Replacing $T$ with $U$ as I suggested gives
$$\vec U(t) =\frac{d}{d t}C(t) =\left(1,2t,-2t-\sin(t)-2t\sin(t^2)\right)$$
so that 
\begin{align}
\| U(t) \|^2 
&= 1^2 + 4t^2 + (2t + \sin t + 2t \sin(t^2))\\
&= 1 + 4t^2 + 4t^2 + \sin^2t + 4t^2 \sin^2 t^2  \\
& + 4t \sin t + 4t^2 \sin(t^2) + 4t \sin t \sin t^2\\
&= 1 + 8t^2 + (1 + 4t^2) \sin^2 t + 4t^2 \sin^2 t^2  + 4t \sin t +  4t \sin t \sin t^2\\
\end{align}
which is definitely *not* a constant, and the square root of that mess isn't a constant either. So $U'(t)$ and $T'(t)$ are not even close to being proportional.

There *is* something useful you can do with $U'$ however: you can apply Gram-Schmidt to $U$ and $U'$ to get the component of $U'$ that's perpendicular to $U$. Here goes:

COmpute

$$
S(t) = U'(t) - \frac{(U'(t) \cdot U(t)}{(U(t) \cdot U(t)} U(t)
$$
This evidently lies in the plane spanned by $U$ and $U'$, and (take its dot-prod with $U(t)$ to see this) it is *perpendicular to $U(t)$. Hence it's some multiple of the thing you were looking for, the unit normal $N(t)$.

So to find $N(t)$, you just compute

$$
N(t) = \frac{1}{\|S(t)\|} S(t).
$$

And there you have it -- no need to normalize $U$ in advance with a hideous square root.

Comment: Turning the tangent into unit length is just dividing by a constant, in which case the orientation of the derivative should not change. I have addressed my careless mistakes in the differentiation of functions in the OP, but still the orientation of the normal vector to the curve is wrong.

Comment: I do follow your explanation well in the abstract.

Comment: Your first comment is slightly mistaken: dividing by the length is dividing by a constant...at *each* time $t$. But this constant varies with $t$, and that makes all the difference. See my post-comment addition in my answer.

Comment: I found the normal vector to $C$ at $P$ calculated as the value of $\left(T(t)\wedge T'(t)\right)\wedge T(t).$ In this way there is no need for normalization until the end. Does this sound correct? Any comments?

Comment: Well...that's *a* normal vector. But the one that's used in almost any formula in differential geometry is the UNIT normal, so you'll still want to normalize. As for your formula...if you unwrap it, it looks a whole lot like my Gram-Schmidt. I think it ends up producing something like $\| U(t) \|^2 S(t)$.

Comment: I have been working on a 3D plot for the Frenet triad, and I just realize that, although (normalized or not) the $(T(t)\wedge T'(t))\wedge T(t)$ is giving the right orientation, its norm seems to move in opposite direction to the actual curvature of the curve as appreciated visually. Can you think of why this could be the case?